# Github - Merge to master

Tags: github

I have two different branches release/ver1 and release/ver2 and code base are completely different.

My requirement is to merge to the following:

1) Merge release/ver1 branch to the master and do the build.
2) Followed by the same day, Merge release/ver2 branch to the master and do the build.

Note: I can merge only to the master ( web hooks PR notifications are configured like this and I cannot create new release branches and merge to it)

Whenever I merge, I am getting merge conflict and every time, I need to manually resolve the conflict and as the code base are totally different, it takes lot of time to resolve manually the merge conflict error.

What would be the best resolution for the above situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try at least to activate first [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere)

```
cd /path/to/repo
git config rerere.enabled true
```

If the *same* conflicts are involved in your different merges, `git rerere` would have recorded their resolution and can apply them automatically.
See "[Git Tools - Rerere](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere)".